# Is it possible to sort by lower case in MonetDB?

Tags: sql, monetdb

Is it possible to do an 'Order by lower(field_name)' in MonetDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly it. It's the lower() function.

```
select lower('Hello')
```

will return 'hello'.
And I've confirmed that this works in the 'order by' clause as well.

Comment: @VivekSadh I would, but I have to wait 2 days to accept according to stackoverflow :)